# Which extension contains the class ModelSavingExceptionTranslationHandler?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I need to create a new class which extends ModelSavingExceptionTranslationHandler.

When I try to write it as:

```
import 
 de.hybris.platform.platformbackoffice.services.handlers.ModelSavingExceptionTranslationHandler;
```

I want to know which extension does it belong to so that I configure this in extensioninfo.xml.When I configure platformbackoffice, this is still not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it with IDE features. For example in IntelliJ, press **Select Opened File** (Alt+Shift+1, 1) button after finding class.
ModelSavingExceptionTranslationHandler class in in the **platformbackoffice** extenison.
[image: IntelliJ Project View]

Comment: @myksoft, thanks a lot for your comments. I made an entry in my extensioninfo.xml file as well.However still it is not able to resolve the package name.

Comment: just add jar to the extension classpath in which you are extending it.

Comment: @RaushanKumar, do you mean overriding buildcallbacks.xml?